# Is this formula a KL divergence?

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, entropy

[image]

As everyone knows KL divergence's formula is $KL(p||q) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}p(i)\log (p(i)/q(i))$. In the image, formula(9) is really calculate KL(X||($(UZ^TA^T)$)) , however i have no idea why there is "deep blue rectangle" in the KL divergence formula ? Is the formula(9) is KL or something else ?  Thanks a lot if you can make me sense!

Comment: I think you need to add more background about what you are asking or it's very difficult to guess what you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

they are probabilities and when summed by $\sum_{i,j}$, cancel each other.

Comment: Thanks, I think i know what formula is, it is generalized KL drivergence or(I-divergence). I want to ask you one more question, you said "they are probabilities" but actual they are elements of matrix , not probabilities . Am i right or how can i understand "probabilities" you said ?

Comment: I supposed the matrix entries sum up to 1 for both matrices since you didn't provide any clue about the sum of your matrices. :-)